# Add a comment to SVN file

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm exporting a file in one folder and moving it to production without performing an change, using this command:

> svn export --username user --password passwd --non-interactive --force svn://svnserver.com/trunk/patch/115/sql/TestFile.sql

After the movement I would like to add a comment/tag that file was moved successfully.  For this, I tried the commands below but they didn't work:

```
> svn commit -m " Test" TestFile.sql
svn: '/home//SVNTEST/1' is not a working copy

> svn commit -m "Test" svn://svnserver.com/trunk/patch/115/sql/TestFile.sql
svn: Must give local path (not URL) as the target of a commit
```

Will it be possible if yes how to do so?

Comment: Why should you add a comment to the server that you have exported and placed the file somewhere? Are you also adding comments when you create a working copy (check out)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize, you're copying a file from the repository to your local machine, then you want to somehow indicate in the repository that this action happened.

Without knowing more about your setup, I think creating a tag is probably the most straightforward way to do this.  Use this command:

```
svn copy svn://svnserver.com/trunk/ svn://svnserver.com/tags/115 -m "Test"
```

Use whatever unique key for the tag name (here I used '115' since it seemed like that was a patch identifier).

---

Let's discuss why the commands you tried did not work.

Since you're [*exporting*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.export.html) rather than [*checking out*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.checkout.html) the file, you don't have a [*working copy*](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.tour.initial.html).  Exporting is basically equivalent to downloading a file from an HTTP or FTP server; there are no strings attached.

Now, the subcommand [commit](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html) requires a working copy (in order to know where in the repository to put your local changes), which explains why in the first command you tried the error indicated you aren't in a working copy.  The second command errored because you (I think) are trying to tell SVN the remote location to upload your local `TestFile.sql`, which is not a valid use-case for the commit subcommand.

My suggestion creates a tag, but does so entirely on the server which means you don't need a working copy.

Comment: Happy to help.  If that answered your question, don't forget to click the checkmark.